# Why babel-loader may ignore .babelrc?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I’ve bootstrapped an app using `create-react-app`, then eject it and now configuring it further. But I have a problem, webpack doesn’t respect the presets declared in `.babelrc`?

I have that error, because of “lack” of `stage-1` preset.

> Syntax error: Missing class properties transform

Meanwhile, if I replace loader with a string notation, like this `babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-1`, it works well.

What can be done to fix it?

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
  ]
}
```

Webpack babel loader configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: 'babel',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will ignore your custom `babelrc`. You have to either...

1) provide them in the in webpack config, as you mentioned

2) eject by running `npm run eject` and use a custom `babelrc`

3) use a fork of `create-react-app` like [this one](https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a#.xpqnlt3pg)

`create-react-app` intentionally abstracts away the process of configuring babel. After all, its goal is to remove the headache of setting up a project for people coming to react for the first time or just hoping to get started quickly. Configuring babel is a big part of that headache. Hence, it does not let you configure babel.

It does, however, provide the ability to eject for exactly this reason. See [this github issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/167) for more discussion on this.

Comment: Actually I've already ejected it as you recommended in (2). But it still ignores .babelrc from project root dir.

Comment: Sadly, but there's no [such line](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L150-Lundefined) in "ejected" version of webpack config

Comment: Yes, I just realized that and removed the edit. I am stumped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [`transform-class-properties`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) plugin into `.babelrc` helped. So everything is fine with a loader itself. But still there is no an answer why `stage-1` preset in a `.babelrc` array is ignoring, while with a string notation it works. Hope, it helps someone anyway.

Comment: Would you please explain the solution steps?